# Failed to compile, Module not found

Tags: reactjs

I got the following error after runing a npm start command with a running application in other pcs with no trouble, I have tried cleaning the cache, deleting the package-lock.json file and node_modules folder to recompile, but always get the same error?

Any ideas?

Here'r the complete Error message.

Failed to compile

./src/pages/artistas/Barrios.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../assets/img/recibos/Álvaro-Barrios---Alegría-de-la-paz.jpg' in 'C:\Users\Stefany\Downloads\sanaciones-master\sanaciones-master\src\pages\artistas'

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

--
It is interesting that it seems to work for some miliseconds but then it fails and the error message appears. The paths to the image is correct, since as I mentioned it works perfect in other pcs.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you happen to update the filename with different case? Like make a capital D into a lowercase d?

Comment: you either changed the filename Álvaro-Barrios---Alegría-de-la-paz.jpg or the location of this image that is why you get this error.